# Indents after pushing Enter button in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2, phpstorm-2018.1

I've been using PhpStorm for a long time and I haven't had this problem before. The problem is that when I type some pare tag, for example, `<div></div>` (there is indent from the beginning of the line) and the cursor is in the middle of this tag and after I push Enter button the closing tag just goes to the beginning of the line.

The interesting fact that in `.php` file everything is OK. The problem only with `.html` extension. I just don't know what I could do to make IDE acts like this.

I have already checked all the adjusting in the `Preferences -> Code style -> HTML.` Everything is the same as in PHP (and I've pushed the button "Restore Defaults").

It works like that (after pushing Enter button):

```
      <div>

</div>
```

And I want it be like that:

```
     <div>

     </div>
```

Comment: Do you really need new question when you have this one already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618567/closing-tag-goes-to-the-beggining-of-the-line-after-pushing-enter-button ?? You could just add more details there...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing tag goes to the beggining of the line after pushing Enter button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618567/closing-tag-goes-to-the-beggining-of-the-line-after-pushing-enter-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your other post:

> I put first some indent to the tag and than push "Enter button". So
>   the first part of the tag stays where it was, but the other goes to
>   the beginning of the line

So, you have your code formatted manually so that the indentation differs from the one you'd get when performing **Code > Reformat Code**. *'Smart indent'* (indenting code on `Enter` - **Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys**, **Enter** section) doesn't care about your manual indentation, created indents are based on code style settings rather than your manually created indents. You can turn it off - the next line will always be indented to the same level as previous in this case.

If reformatting the code with **Code > Reformat Code** doesn't help, it must be the issue with either the code formatting preferences or file associations... Do you have any custom plugins installed? [Svelte](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10021-svelte) plugin, for example, registers `.html` files as *Svelte Html Components* (https://github.com/dschulten/sveltejs-idea-plugin/issues/2, https://github.com/dschulten/sveltejs-idea-plugin/issues/6), causing similar issues.

Please also check if **Keep white spaces** option is enabled in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other** - when it's ON, existing indents don't change on reformatting

Comment: Hello Lena!

Thanks a lot for your answer, but unfortunately in doesn't work. 

Firs, I Reformatted code before pushing Enter, but it didn't help. Then I turned off 'Smart indent' and the result the same. I even reinstalled the program yesterday (before that I'd deleted all the config files), but the result the same :) 

Interesting fact is that there is no problem with the .php extension. So, I will probably just work with .php extension instead of .html. 

Couple screenshots:

Comment: Yes, It helped! :) It was because of this Svelte plugin! I've removed it.

Now I push Code | Reformat Code and I can see changes and everything works how it should. 

But I don't remember installing it...

And again thank you a lot! :)